# Google Pay integration using Braintree Drop-In UI

Tags: android, braintree, braintree-sandbox, google-pay

I have completed integrating the Braintree gateway as my payments processor in my Android app. I use the Drop-In UI to complete the payments with the Google Pay option enabled. Everything is working as expected in the Sandbox environment and now I have created a producrtion account and got approved by Braintree.

In order to enable the Google Pay option I have to get my app reviewed by Google as well, following the process listed in the link below:
[Google Pay integration checklist](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/test-and-deploy/integration-checklist)

Among other things, the docs state that I have to use the WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST when I submit my app.

I don't think the Google Pay initilization is editable by the drop in sdk, so there is nowhere in the [Braintree Google Pay setup](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/google-pay/client-side/android/v2) a way to set the WalletOptions environment to WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST. So should I send a Sandbox build/account of my app for review? Does Braintree's Sandbox corresponds to setting the environment parameter from WalletOptionsWalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST?

It's a simple question, but Braintree support did not have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The android Drop-in UI has a [dependency](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-android-drop-in/blob/master/Drop-In/build.gradle#L54) on Braintree's Android SDK. In the Android SDK, the [`WalletOptions` environment](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_android/blob/master/Braintree/src/main/java/com/braintreepayments/api/GooglePayment.java#L88-L91) is determined based on whether you are initializing the Braintree environment with sandbox or production credentials.

So if you create an app using Braintree sandbox credentials, `WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST` should be set for you.